# Why a straight line is the shortest path between two points?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, metric-tensor, geodesics

There is a geometric proof, the triangle inequality.

But is there a way to prove this by means of the first law of Newton?

Comment: I don't see how Newtons first law could be used to prove that...  I think you need to elaborate more on why you expect Newtons first law to prove something in geometry.  I can see somewhat how the two are tied together, but I would think Newtonian physics relies on geometry, and doesn't act as a way to prove it.

Comment: Geometry, as used in physics, especially in Newtonian physics, is based on Euclidian geometry. Whatever Newton derived, is derived. Maybe or may not be there is a way to conclude backwards from Newtonian mechanics to Euclidian geometry. This would rather by a question of mathematics then of physics.

Answer (score 2):

> Why a straight line is the shortest path between two points?

It isn't. The [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) is the shortest path between two points.

The geodesic reduces to a straight line only in cartesian coordinates. Those are not the coordinates we live in, although it's close. The difference between the two is what we call "gravity".